# download file with php 

Tags: php, xampp

i just wondering. so this
i have 2 computers which the one was installed xampp and the other one was not.(same network). both is windows xp

and i making up this script for test download the file.

```
<?php
$txt = "http://www.branded3.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Google_Chrome1.jpg";
$img = "01.jpg";
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($txt));
?>
```

and i run the script on my computer which xampp is installed, and its absolutely works.

but i running it on my another computer, not working.
can anybody help me in this issue?

Comment: This one made me chuckle. ;p.... #Are you expecting it to download the file on the client machine?

Comment: what are you running on the other pc if not xampp?

Comment: No its not, php is server based it runs on the server, tho you could use the server to proxy the image and prompt you to download.

Comment: I direct server ip in the browser and run the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a very crude way you can proxy the image and prompt a download.

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.branded3.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Google_Chrome1.jpg";

//Get file
$source = file_get_contents($url);

//Image Mime types
$images = array('jpg'=>'image/jpg','png'=>'image/png','png'=>'image/png');
//Is it an image extention
if(in_array(substr($url,-3),$images)){
    $type = $images[substr($url,-3)];
}else{
    //No its somthing else
    $type = 'application/octet-stream';
}

//Set the headers
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: '.$type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($url));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . sprintf("%u", strlen($source)));
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: public');

//echo the source
echo $source;
?>
```

Comment: you made it :), thank you very much.!!!.. 
but how do i specify the path to download? and ignore the download window while on firefox or explorer(automatically download).

Comment: I doesn't work like that you cant put a file on a client computer without prompting a download, think of the security implications. With specifying a path you could use $_GET['url'] ect